# saving model to database throw ValueError in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two model employee and department. Employee has one to one connection with department like

```
class Employee(models.Model): 
      department = models.ForeignKey(to=Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

but when I try to create object from rest request, it throws

> ValueError: Cannot assign "{'id': 1, 'name': 'wrewrwerwe'}": "Employee.department" must be a "Department" instance.

Comment: Show us the relevant views..

Comment: Can you share the code fragment (likely view) where you *create* the `Employee` model object.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are posting a JSON, with a field `department` which is the primary key of the department you want to link (or a JSON representing the department).

When creating your model, you must not provide the primary key of the department for the `department` keywork, but provide a `Department` object.

In your view, you should do :

```py
# You have data like : {"department": {"id": 1, "name": "wrewrwerwe"}, with 1 the department's PK
department = Department.objects.get(pk=data["department"]["id"])
employee = Employee(department=department)
employee.save()   # Should work
```